# код страницы отличается от кода элемента

Tags: html, python

Я учусь делать парсинг страниц, и у меня возникла проблема: заметил, что на некоторых сайтах код элемента совершенно отличается от кода страницы. С чем это связанно и как парсить с помощью кода элемента?

Comment: что ты имеешь ввиду под "кодом страницы" и "кодом элемента"?

Comment: @Grundy скорее всего, код страницы - page source, а кол элемента - тот, что внутри инструментов разработчика

Comment: Не удивительно, что код элемента будет отличаться от кода страницы, внутри которой этот элемент:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое происходит по той причине, что во втором случае вы смотрите page source (исходный код страницы), а когда вы смотрите код элемента - отображается текущий(!) код страницы, который может изменяться скриптами (например, JS), прикрученными к странице.